# Reading PHP file size over 2 GB

Tags: php, upload, filesize

Let me preface this my saying I've been coding for a long time, however I'm only good at HTML and Perl - my experience with PHP is extremely limited so I'm basically a straight up noob when it comes to PHP.  But, the times dictate I try to make it work for me as Perl is not going to cut it.

What I am trying to do is this...   I have a script that is attempting to pull the file size of a file on the server and use it for various purposes (display, calculation, etc).  The script is the upload handler from the blueimp jQuery-File-Upload's UploadHander.php script.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

The problem is when it tries reading and working with files over 2 GB as the server I'm operating on (much to my dismay, and I can't change it) is 32 bit.

So here's the issue... the script pulls the file size using the filesize() function.  The file is over 2GB so it errors out.  I found a simple workaround function that successfully pulls the file size from the server and displays it perfectly, but when I try to integrate it into the UploadHandler.php script it doesn't work....

Here's the function that tries to pull the filesize:

```
protected function fix_integer_overflow($size) {
    if ($size < 0) {
        $size += 2.0 * (PHP_INT_MAX + 1);
    }
    return $size;
}

protected function get_file_size($file_path, $clear_stat_cache = false) {
    if ($clear_stat_cache) {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
            clearstatcache(true, $file_path);
        } else {
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }
    return $this->fix_integer_overflow(filesize($file_path));
}
```

Here's the function someone wrote that does, when run alone, successfully pull the full file size from the server:

```
protected function filesize2($path) {
  $sizeInBytes = @filesize($path);
  if($sizeInBytes===false) {
    $command = "/bin/ls -l ".escapeshellarg($path);
    $ret = trim(exec($command)); 
    if(!substr_count($ret, "ls:") && !substr_count($ret, "Aucun fichier")) {
      $ret = str_replace("\t", " ", $ret);
      $ret = str_replace("  ", " ", $ret);
      $ret = str_replace("  ", " ", $ret);
      $ret = str_replace("  ", " ", $ret);
      $arr = explode(" ", $ret);
      $sizeInBytes = $arr[4];
    }
  }
  return $sizeInBytes;
}
```

So I know the original code works as it works perfectly with smaller files, and I know the code to pull the larger file size works as it does just fine independently, and the UploadHander.php script works when I put the filesize2() function code into it without making the script access it, but when I replace this:

```
return $this->fix_integer_overflow(filesize($file_path));
```

With this:

```
return $this->fix_integer_overflow(filesize2($file_path));
```

the UploadHandler.php script no longer functions at all even when only presented with smaller files......   I've tried everything I can think of, I've researched everything I can on here and other forums on other sites, and I'm stuck.  Hoping an experienced PHP coder will know what I'm doing wrong and be able to help me get this working properly.  Seems like this should be simple but it's clearly not!  Thanks for reading.

Comment: With the presence of the 'protected' statement you're obviously dealing with a class, can you post the entire class you are using and editing? and also the script ( or a portion of the script ) where you are calling these methods/function for context?

Comment: What error are you getting?. You should remove the @ before the filesize function in filesize2, since it suppresses the error message. Also see this sample code on the php.net website (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#121406). It allows getting the filesize for files larger than 2GB

Comment: I honestly don't know enough about PHP to tell you what class is being used, what protected means, why it's not working when I try to use a different method for getting the file size, etc.  There's no error message per say.  It simple doesn't pull the file sizes for any file in the directory no matter how big or small and therefore doesn't display any of the files it should be displaying..  Here's a link to the full code for the script:  If you can tell me how to get it working I'd be very grateful.  http://www.daggs.com/UploadHandler.txt

Comment: @NadirLatif I tried using the one you linked instead of using the filesize2 function I was trying.  Same effect.  I don't know what's going wrong with the script because I don't know enough about PHP to diagnose it.  The UploadHandler.php script doesn't have any output of it's own, it's just used to upload and save files and then display the existing file list.  When I make changes to the code, it simply stops displaying the list of files and won't let me upload anything of any size.  So I'm assuming the script isn't working at all at that point but I can't see error messages.

Comment: @John I posted a link to the whole script - hopefully you can look through it and see what exactly I'm doing wrong that's killing it?  I have no clue what I'm doing with PHP unfortunately.  If this was written in Perl I'd be fine lol